# AngularJS Button Click bind value to input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a number pad with AngularJS where the input field can receive the input value by pressing the number button or by typing in a value manually.

My controller code:

```
app.controller('LoginFormController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.numPass = [];

    $scope.num = function(number){
        $scope.numPass.push(number);
        $scope.input = $scope.numPass;
        console.log(number)
    };
}]);
```

My HTML template code:

```
<form class="login-form" ng-controller="LoginFormController">
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" >
    <div class="col-5">
        <input ng-model="input" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical numpad mx-4 my-3" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <div class="row d-flex-flex-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <button type="button" ng-click="num(1)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-bottom-0 num-blue">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-bottom-0 num-blue">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-bottom-0 num-blue">3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex-flex-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-bottom-0 num-blue">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-bottom-0 num-blue">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-bottom-0 num-blue">6</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex-flex-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary num-blue">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary num-blue">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary num-blue">9</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex-flex-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary num-blue">0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary red-arrow"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/web_images/Arrow-Left-Icon.png" alt=""></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary red-arrow"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/web_images/Arrow-Left-Double-Icon.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-center btn-group submit-buttons btn-group-lg">
            <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="col-3 btn-clock-in btn btn-primary">Clock In<img class="img-fluid" src="images/web_images/clock-in-icon.png" alt="Clock In"></button>
            <button type="submit" class="col-2 btn btn-force">Force</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

This works a little bit but I'm sure there is a better way of achieving it. without having to create an array and then binding the array to the input field.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, things that could be improved on.

I would use ngRepeate to display the keypads. For example:

```
 function keypadNumber($scope) {
  $scope.keypad = [{number: 1}, {number: 2}, {number: 3}];
}



<div class="row d-flex-flex-row justify-content-center">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
    <button ng-repeat="(key, value) in keypad" ng-click="keypadNumber({keypad.number})">{{keypad}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement the ng-repeat code that you provided, but it didn't work. I agree looping the buttons defiantly would be better.

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle so I can take look at the code and see where it is breaking?

Comment: I setup one up I only added the number pad. Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/taylorg/ndz0kas3/3/#&togetherjs=9t0azGoBLz

Comment: I removed the unnecessary noice and focused on the problem. When I find myself trouble shooting a problem, I often will create a separate project (POC) and start simple. Here is a simple example of what you want to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/dannielrolfe/shy8d6mw/12/

Comment: I was able to figure out my problem last night. I'm going to work on getting my loop to work so I don't have the static buttons. Thank you for help.

Comment: Great! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that was causing my onclick to not bind to my input field was that I was passing them to an array rather than passing them to an empty string.

```
 $scope.numPass = [];
```

When I should have been using this instead

```
 $scope.numPass = '';
```